# unit test, Sinon js spies

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

So i have this little function

```
module.exports = {
  setupNewUser(info, callback) {
    var user = {
      name: info.name,
      nameLowercase: info.name.toLowerCase()
    }

    try {
      Database.save(user, callback)
    }
    catch(err) {
      callback(err)
    }
  }
}
```

and im using sinon to test this method

```
const setupNewUser = require('./index').setupNewUser
const sinon = require('sinon')
const assert = require('assert')

const Database = {
  save(info, cb) {
    if (info === undefined) {
      return cb('nope')
    } else {
      return cb()
    }
  }
}

describe('#save()', function () {
  it('should call save once', function() {
    var save = sinon.spy(Database, 'save')

    setupNewUser({ name: 'test' }, function() { })

    save.restore()
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(save)
  })
})
```

When i ran the test it fail any knows why ?

Error message

> AssertError: expected save to be called once but was called 0 times

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason this is happening is because you're not actually stubbing out the method you think you are. In your test code, your intention was to create a fake `Database` object so that your actual source code will call this object's method. What you need to stub out is that actual `Database` object that your source code uses.

Normally in your source code, you'd probably import the `Database` object. You'll need to import the same `Database` object and stub it out in your test code as well.